# xmlファイルの操作

Tags: python, python3

xmlファイルから一定の場所のテキストの内容を抽出し、テキストファイルに格納し,csvファイルとテキストファイルの中の全文との共起語を抽出し、その共起語の数と付与されているidを出力させるプログラムを作成したい.

```
実行結果　例)
(共通している用語　　　　共通している用語の個数  用語に付与されているid)

    acute                        2                   0000
    distress                     1                   0000
    coronavirus                  1                   1111
    China                        2                   1111

(付与されているid     そのidの個数)
      0000                3
      1111                3
```

ソースコード

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#xmlファイル読み込み
with open('ab36_37.xml','r',encoding='utf-8') as xml:      
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

#passageの中のparagraphのテキストのCOVID-19とSARS-CoV-2の文字列を抽出

texts = soup.select('''
passage >
  infon[key="type"]:-soup-contains("paragraph") ~ text:-soup-contains("SARS-CoV-2")
''')
text = [t.text for t in texts]
xml.close()

#実行結果を指定のファイルに保存
with open ('re_ab3637.txt','w')as txt:
  print('\n'.join(text),file=txt)
txt.close
```

csvファイル　例

```
0000,acute
0000,distress
1111,coronavirus
1111,China
```

テキストファイル　例

```
Severe acute respiratory distress syndrome due to acute coronavirus (SARS-CoV-2), which was first diagnosed in China, China in December 2019.
```

Comment: 共起語ってなんですか？ 「あるキーワードと同時もしくは頻繁に出現する単語」という定義が出てきましたが「共起語の数」というのがよくわかりません。単語（ID)のペア⇒回数という結果がほしいということですか？　re_ab3637.txt の中身のサンプルに対してどういう結果がほしいかのサンプルも描いてほしいです

Comment: [過去の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91923) にもコメントしましたが、作りたいものに対して **何に困っているのか、分からないのか** を具体的に説明してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ただCSVにでてくる単語をサンプルテキストから数えるだけってことですよね？
共起っていう表現を使うから難しくきこえるだけで
文字列から文字列の出現頻度を数えるメソッドがあるので結構簡単にできます
https://hibiki-press.tech/python/count/103

ファイル名は適宜変更してください

```
def main():
    # IDと単語のかかれたCSVを１行ずつ配列にする
    with open('words.csv','r') as f:
        rows = f.readlines()

    # 探す文章をまるごと１つの文字列に入れる
    with open('re_ab3637.txt','r') as f:
        text = f.read()

    # id => count へのマップ
    id_count = {}

    with open('result1.csv','w') as f:
        for row in rows:
            # id,word という文字列を , で分割
            tmp = row.split(',')
            id = tmp[0]
            # 改行ついてるので取り除く
            word = tmp[1].strip()
            # text に word が何回入ってるか数える
            count = text.count(word)
            f.write('%s,%d,%s\n' % (word, count, id))

            # id がすでにあったらカウント追加する
            if id in id_count:
                id_count[id] += count
            else: # なかったらエントリ作成する
                id_count[id] = count

    # id => count を出力
    with open('result2.csv','w') as f:
        for id, count in id_count.items():
            f.write('%s,%d\n' % (id, count))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

result1.csv

```
acute,2,0000
distress,1,0000
coronavirus,1,1111
China,2,1111
```

result2.csv

```
0000,3
1111,3
```